# Where can I get a PalmOS SDK?

Tags: c, linux, sdk, palm-os

Where can I get a  PalmOS SDK? - To use with PRC tools under Linux.

Palm/HP dont have them any more, and Access never send you the confirmation email....

I know C, I just cant get my hands on an SDK and docs anywhere...

I just want to work with the serial port. - Will be building on Linux (GCC/PRC tools)

Answer (score 2):

several years later, and after hard web digging

http://web.archive.org/web/20141224205957/http://cdn.xenu.tk/pub/palm-archive/pub/programming/sdk/

it seems to have all SDks, hopefully now I should be able to program my good old Palm Pilot to interface with arduino or something like it.

UPDATE(also years later): https://github.com/acesso/palm-os-sdk I get a collection of (old)palm SDK going here

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but since accessdevnet.com seems to have gone away here's a mirror of the PalmOS SDK, version 5.0r3:

https://www.mediafire.com/?d2bxy382mk0mdae

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for 'palm os sdk' led to the HP Developers site with a link for the download at the top:

https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/sdk_pdk_download.html

Comment: Yeah, but google is wrong. That page now has the WEB OS SDK. Web OS (Used on the TouchPad) is the new (totally different) replacement for the old PalmOS (As used on the Pilot etc...)

Comment: Yeah, and that says to download the SDK from http://www.palmos.com/dev/tools/index.html, which redirects to http://www.accessdevnet.com/, which never emails you back. - as was stated in the question.

Comment: Not sure where you're looking. I'm looking at sourceforge... http://sourceforge.net/projects/prc-tools/files/

Comment: Yeah, PRC tools is the compiler, but the PRC tools page says you still need the Palm SDK for the libaries + headers to actually build anything.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I'd be surprised if it can't be found. Did you try torrent sites or P2P sharing?